# Is it accepted by Sunni scholars that Imam Ali a.s performed Keramat?

Tags: sunni, ali

The story of death of [Salman Al-Farsi r.a.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salman_the_Persian) the Persian Sahabi of prophet is mentioned in different Shia books like [this reference](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/MagArt.html?MagazineArticleID=58305&MagazineNumberID=5789). It includes that Imam Ali passed a long distance in *very* short period of time, this action is called [Tay al-Arz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tay_al-Arz) طي الأرض and is considered as a kind of [Keramat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keramat) and is mentioned in this verse:

> قَالَ الَّذِي عِندَهُ عِلْمٌ مِّنَ الْكِتَابِ أَنَا آتِيكَ بِهِ قَبْلَ
> أَن يَرْتَدَّ إِلَيْكَ طَرْفُكَ ۚ فَلَمَّا رَآهُ مُسْتَقِرًّا عِندَهُ
> قَالَ هَٰذَا مِن فَضْلِ رَبِّي لِيَبْلُوَنِي أَأَشْكُرُ أَمْ أَكْفُرُ
> ۖ وَمَن شَكَرَ فَإِنَّمَا يَشْكُرُ لِنَفْسِهِ ۖ وَمَن كَفَرَ فَإِنَّ
> رَبِّي غَنِيٌّ كَرِيمٌ
>
> Muhsin Khan Translation:
>
> One with whom was knowledge of the Scripture said: "I will bring it to
> you within the twinkling of an eye!" then when [Sulaiman (Solomon)]
> saw it placed before him, he said: "This is by the Grace of my Lord to
> test me whether I am grateful or ungrateful! And whoever is grateful,
> truly, his gratitude is for (the good of) his ownself, and whoever is
> ungrateful, (he is ungrateful only for the loss of his ownself).
> Certainly! My Lord is Rich (Free of all wants), Bountiful."
>
> [[Surat An-Naml:40]](http://quran.com/27/40)

According to Shia theology, it is believed that Imams and some of very pious scholars had and have this ability granted by Allah. There are many stories recorded in different books that says Imams and many of scholars did Tay al-Arz but usually they keep this ability secret from public and only their near friends know it.

Tay al-Arz is part of "knowledge of Kitab" mentioned in the Quran and hadith. it is narrated in a hadith (I think from Sunni also)

> Abu Saeed Khidri asked from prophet who is "who has some of knowledge
> of Kitab" [الَّذِي عِندَهُ عِلْمٌ مِّنَ الْكِتَابِ](http://tanzil.net/#27:40) in the Quran?
> prophet replied: he is executor of my brother Solomon. then I asked
> and who is "who has knowledge of Kitab" [مَنْ عِندَهُ عِلْمُ
> الْكِتَابِ](http://tanzil.net/#13:43) in the Quran? prophet replied he is my brother Ali Ibn
> Abi Talib
>
> جلد 3 احقاق الحق صفحه 280- 281
>
> نور الثقلین جلد 2 صفحه 523

Comment: It might be useful to quote the references of the sunni books which mention this event.

Comment: And please quote some of the text of the event too, if you have access to it.

Comment: @Abdullah could not find ir in sunni books. a sunni brother told it past and I could not find that text now. so I changed the question.

Comment: @Ahmadi This is basically Karamah. The Sunnis believe in the Karamah that have been authentically reported. One I came across is that of Umar (radiallahu anhu). It is reported in many books as a hadith. However I couldn't find this one by Ali (radiallahu anhu) in any books. It would be better if you could find any Sunni hadith (like Muslim, Bukhari, Musnad) that mentions this event or change the question to general (as in do sunnis believe in karamah?).

Comment: @Ahmadi: *Tay al-Arz is part of "knowledge of Kitab"* could you explain that please? I didn't understand the connection between both.

Comment: @Mr.TAMER according to definition of [Tay al-Arz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tay_al-Arz) the action one companion of prophet Solomon a.s. did in [this verse](http://quran.com/27/40) i.e. bringing within the twinkling of an eye, is a Tay al-Arz and Quran says he had could do this Tay al-Arz necause he had knowledge of Kitab. so Tay al-Arz is part of knowledge of Kitab.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Sunni scholars accept Karamat in General, among which those of Imam Ali <sup>may Allah be pleased with him and honor his face</sup>.

Here you a book by [Imam Lalikani](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/showalam.php?ids=15113) (or Lalika'a) called "[Describing the principles of beliefs of Ahl Al-Sunnah wa Al-Jama'ah شرح أصول اعتقاد أهل السنة والجماعة](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1&idto=291&lang=&bk_no=110&ID=1)", it contains a chapter called "[Karamat of Awliaa' Allah كرامات أولياء الله the semi-miracles of saints (very pious people)](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=193&idto=291&lang=&bk_no=110&ID=182)", which contains a [section about the Karamat of Caliph Ali](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=110&ID=204) <sup>may Allah be pleased with him an honor his face</sup> in a reporting matter (not exclusive). Among which he mentions:

> That one man came and told him something that is a lie, Ali replied: "You lied to me", the man said: "No I didn't", Ali replied: "Do you accept that I ask Allah something against you if you were lying?" The man said: "Yes", Ali did that, and the man turned blind before leaving Ali.

The book also mentions evidences about the existence of Karamat from Quran and Sunnah, but I won't talk about that here as the question doesn't ask about it.

*Hope that's helpful.*